# QWebEngineView crashes on Windows release builds as it can't find the required resource files

Tags: windows, qt, qt-installer, qwebengineview, windeployqt

I am currently developing an application for Windows using Qt 5.9 that displays some local HTML files inside using a [`QWebEngineView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html) instance. The code is rather simple, and I don't think it is relevant to the issue at hand:

```
QWebEngineView *webView = new QWebEngineView(this);
webView->setUrl(QUrl("qrc:/my_view.html"));
```

This works nicely on my development machine, on both debug and release configurations. My application is already on production and as such it can be installed using the [Qt Installer Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/). I am using [windeployqt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) for deployment. Again, the installed binary works renders the web pages on my machine with no issues. However, on a different machine with the same OS, it will crash whenever the web view is instantiated.

After some debugging, here are my discoveries:

According to [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-deploying.html) on the web engine:

> Qt WebEngine requires the following resource files:

> qtwebengine_resources.pak contains the resources needed by Chromium.
> qtwebengine_devtools_resources.pak contains tools for remote debugging.
> qtwebengine_resources_100p.pak contains images suitable for low resolution displays.
> qtwebengine_resources_200p.pak contains images suitable for high DPI displays.
> icudtl.dat provides support for International Components for Unicode (ICU). It is the Chromium version of ICU, which is not needed if Qt WebEngine was configured to use the system ICU.

> Resources are searched from the following locations:

> On Linux and Windows: the resources directory in the directory specified by QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::DataPath)

Which I found odd, since the output of the application directory yields the following (trimmed for convenience):

```
│   app.exe
|   <other libraries>
│   Qt5WebChannel.dll
│   Qt5WebEngineCore.dll
│   Qt5WebEngineWidgets.dll
│   QtWebEngineProcess.exe
│
├───bearer
│
├───iconengines
│
├───imageformats
│
├───Licenses
│
├───platforms
│
├───position
│
├───printsupport
│
├───resources
│       icudtl.dat
│       qtwebengine_devtools_resources.pak
│       qtwebengine_resources.pak
│       qtwebengine_resources_100p.pak
│       qtwebengine_resources_200p.pak
│
├───sqldrivers
│
└───translations
    └───qtwebengine_locales
```

Which clearly shows that the web engine files are in theory properly located. I tried debugging the value of `QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::DataPath)`, and it yielded `C:/Qt/Qt5.9.2/5.9.2/msvc2017_64`, which isn't even a directory on the target machine, but rather on my development PC. Instead, I think it should output the path to `./resources`.

If I place the files mentioned in the docs in the same directory as the application binary it runs as it should, but I would have expected the `QLibraryInfo::DataPath` to automatically detect where this directory is instead of, by the looks of it, being a hard-coded value.

As such I would like to ask the following:

- Am I doing this deployment correctly? I have never had any problems with the application being unable to load the Qt libraries of any sort, and the files seem to be where they should be.
- How does `QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::DataPath)` exactly resolve paths? Are they hard coded values or are they determined during runtime?
- What would be the most sensible way to make the application find the resources? I am thinking of the following solutions:

  - Manually place the files under `./resources` close to the application binary.
  - Adding the `./resources` to the search path with [`QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath) (I am not sure if it will work).
  - Play around with a [`qt.conf`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) file. Again unsure if it will work. **Edited**: This does indeed work. Oddly enough it did not if the file was compiled as a Qt resource (as in `:/qt/etc/qt.conf`), but if you place the text file along the application binary it will automatically use it. My file looks simply like this:

    [Paths]
    Data = ./resources